# Why citet doesn't work in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I have a problem. Why 'citet' doesn't work in beamer?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{indentfirst,multicol,amssymb}

\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl} 

\usepackage[sort]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Books}

\begin{enumerate}

    \item \citet{bra}
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame} 
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What does 'doesn't work mean'? Do you get an error?

Comment: Can you go back to your previous questions and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Answer (score 2):

A `\bibliographystyle` is missing. For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[sort]{natbib}

% to generate some dummy bib entry, as no one was in the question %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{knuth,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX} book},
  year         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  sortyear     = {1984-1},
  sorttitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting A},
  indexsorttitle= {The TeXbook},
  indextitle   = {\protect\TeX book, The},
  shorttitle   = {\TeX book}
}
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Books}

\begin{enumerate}

    \item \citet{knuth}
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try it. But actually I have more than one literature to be cited?!

Comment: @Yang-Hui More bibitems are no problem.

Comment: But my bib document also contains other literature. Can I use my original bid file? Not create a new one?

Comment: @Yang-Hui No problem. As the code you provided in the question did not contain any `.bib` entries, I was just too lacy to add more than one.